# revtex reporting underfull hbox at every newline

Tags: line-breaking, captions, warnings, revtex

So I'm working on a seminar, and I was wondering, why revtex, every time I make newline after a paragraph (\), reports underfull hbox warning? I mean, everything looks fine once in pdf (I would expect some weird text behavior).

The MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,prc,floats,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvipdfm,colorlinks=true,bookmarks=false,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=red,pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.00}]{hyperref}
\usepackage[font={small}]{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=297mm,centering, hmargin=1.5cm, vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipis-
cing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam
arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a,
magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque
habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra me-
tus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla
ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida pla-
cerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra
ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum.
Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pul-
vinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla.
Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu,
accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit
amet orci dignissim rutrum.\\


Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitu-
din vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus
libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Do-
nec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula
aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac
orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras
nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque pena-
tibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vesti-
bulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.

Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat, con-
gue non, volutpat at, tincidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus
viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy pellentesque
ante. Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. Proin fermentum
massa ac quam. Sed diam turpis, molestie vitae, placerat
a, molestie nec, leo. Maecenas lacinia. Nam ipsum ligula,
eleifend at, accumsan nec, suscipit a, ipsum. Morbi blan-
dit ligula feugiat magna. Nunc eleifend consequat lorem.
Sed lacinia nulla vitae enim. Pellentesque tincidunt purus
vel magna. Integer non enim. Praesent euismod nunc eu
purus. Donec bibendum quam in tellus. Nullam cursus
pulvinar lectus. Donec et mi. Nam vulputate metus eu
enim. Vestibulum pellentesque felis eu massa.


\end{document}
```

The warnings are

```
line 0:  Unsupported document class (or package) detected,(caption) usage of the caption package is not recommended.
line 0:  \caption will not be redefined since it's already(caption) redefined by a document class or package which is(caption) unknown to the caption package.
line 24: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
```

When I compile images or tables in my other file, again, in pdf everything looks fine, but the warning is given :
Do revtex and caption don't like each other or?

Thanks on clarification of this bizzare event :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many unrelated questions.

(1) Never use `\\` to "leave a blank line", but

```
... end of paragraph.

\medskip % or \bigskip

Start of a new paragraph ...
```

(2) caption doesn't work with revtex, which is a specialized format with its own style for captions that's not to be modified by users, since it's used for submissions to journals.

Comment: What's wrong with \\?

Oh and, I just use caption but don't use it explicitly with \usepackage{caption}?

Comment: nothing wrong with \\ in its place.  it forces a line break, but does nothing about filling the line, so to the tex engine, the broken line looks "underfull".

Comment: nothing wrong with \\ in its place.  in a normal paragraph it merely breaks the line prematurely, and the bleeding chunk left behind looks underfull to the tex engine.  its place (apart from tabulars and arrays) is "special" paragraphs, such as in the center environment, where it's the mechanism for adjusting line breaks -- never easy to do automatically.